# What is a better approach to AlertDialog?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application, dialog, alerts

Let's put it this way;
What is a better approach when you ask user to confirm/reject something while need to choose a value in a mobile application?

I have the following options:

1. Scroll-able content.

   - Just like what Google suggested in [here](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-behavior).
2. predefined value in application Settings.

   - To set it before-hand by user.
3. etc..

edit:
Accepted the answer because I needed more clarifications that actually happened to be in the first reply. In my approach I will need to present a **large list** to the user which should be placed in the *Application Settings* cause it is not a well-formed approach to put it in a pop up.
Better solution for this case is point 3 in the accepted answer!

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information. Could you please elaborate the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to choose one of the options that you have come up with it would require more knowledge of the "**something**" that you want your users to confirm/reject.

1. **Scroll-able content.** This would be a good option if you have only a limited number of values to choose from; *eg. 5-6*. This would not be a good solution if you provide a large number of options in a small pop up and asking the users to make a selection.
2. **Default value in Application Settings.** You can use this option only if the "*something*" is not a critical element in you application.
3. **Pop up with an action to go to Application Setting and choose a value.** This option can be used only if the particular "*something*" is a really important setting and require more space to choose form a large number of options or to explain its details to the user. Also, this way the user can be aware where actually the setting is located to change the value in a later point of time.